# Include Angular file in layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to include my angular file(Layout.js) inside my _Layout.cshtml.
So I added it at the end of the page like this:-

```
    @section Scripts{
    <script src="~/Angular_Files/Layout.js"></script> 
}
```

This does work but only for the index page. Whenever I click on another link say course.cshtml, my angular file(Layout.js) doesn't get included.

PS: I tried to explain the best I can. Feel free if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Angular is usually used for a single page app so not at all clear what you are trying to do here. Seems you have front end and back end far too tightly coupled

Comment: Thanks for comment. What I want to do is include all my constants in a class and load them dynamically in my layout page with help of angular class. So that when I change once it'll be changed at all places.

Comment: you're using angular just to load a few constants? Seems like overkill

Comment: @ADyson sorry didn't get you.

Comment: you said "What I want to do is include all my constants in a class and load them dynamically in my layout page". My question was why do you need angular for that?

Comment: Oh. Is there a better approach? I don't want to put some static values in those fields though.

Comment: well you can just define some normal JS variables, I would think. Do your other views actually use/require Angular? It's not clear.

Comment: Can you share link to any example? Yes every one of my views require angular

Comment: You really need to provide a [mcve]. This seems like an unusual angular use case

Comment: @charlietfl that would make the question really long!!

Comment: Not asking for your whole app code...just an example of what you are doing(or trying to do). A typical angular app only involves one html page and has client side routes. Just sounds like you are using the wrong tools